# Usage of the word "champ" when speaking about champignons

Tags: word-usage

Can the shortened word "champ" be used when speaking about champignons (mushrooms), not about champions?

There is definitely a wordplay in [the name of the company](https://www.champsmushrooms.ca/): champsmushrooms

Answer (score 1):

I’ve never read or heard of [champ](https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&ei=0_sTWpmmKsHaU9S1gpgO&q=define%20of%20%20champ&oq=define%20of%20%20champ&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3..0i30k1l4j0i8i30k1.9842.11760.0.12107.6.6.0.0.0.0.126.670.2j4.6.0....0...1c..64.mobile-gws-serp..0.6.669...0i7i30i19k1j0i19k1j0i7i30k1j0i7i5i30k1j0i8i7i30k1j0i7i10i30k1.0.IFmJKiZRjw4) as a short for champignons and  I could find no reference about it.

You can personally use champ for champignons, of course, but you may be misunderstood or asked to clarify what you mean.

Actually, according  the [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/champignon) champignons is the short for:

> (British): 
>   short for ***fairy ring champignon***.